# Mysql I'm combining tables. But I can not do filter sorting

Tags: php, mysql

I combine tables with `group_concat`. But I can not do filter sorting. How can I do it? Order by `ads_filter_option.filter_option` `asc` or `desc` not working.

[SQL-FIDDLE-TABLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61b36/1)

```
select
ads.id,
ads.ad_title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter.filter_title SEPARATOR ','),
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',')
from ads
LEFT JOIN ads_filter_option
on find_in_set(ads_filter_option.id,ads.filter_option_id)
LEFT JOIN ads_filter
on ads_filter.id=ads_filter_option.filter_id
where cat_1 = 2
group by ads.id
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Filtering usually means reducing the rows returned using WHERE or HAVING, while sorting refers to the order of the rows returned.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61b36/1

Comment: Black
  Black
  Black
  Black
  White
  
  or
  
  1.6 Engine
  1.6 Engine
  1.6 Engine
  2.0 Engine
  2.0 Engine

like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. What about this result is different from what you are trying to do?

```
select
ads.id,
ads.ad_title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter.filter_title SEPARATOR ','),
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',')
from ads
LEFT JOIN ads_filter_option
on find_in_set(ads_filter_option.id,ads.filter_option_id)
LEFT JOIN ads_filter
on ads_filter.id=ads_filter_option.filter_id
where cat_1 = 2
group by ads.id
order by GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',')
```

If you also want to order by the option type, try this:

```
select
ads.id,
ads.ad_title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter.filter_title SEPARATOR ','),
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',')
from ads
LEFT JOIN ads_filter_option
on find_in_set(ads_filter_option.id,ads.filter_option_id)
LEFT JOIN ads_filter
on ads_filter.id=ads_filter_option.filter_id
where cat_1 = 2
group by ads.id
order by ads_filter.filter_title,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',')
```

Here's the results of the 2nd query:

```
| id |                                                    ad_title | GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter.filter_title SEPARATOR ',') | GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',') |
|----|-------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 64 |                   Kiralık Araçlar deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                        Color |                                                                Black |
| 59 |                          Otomobil deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 61 |              Arazi, SUV & Pick-up deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 63 |                    Ticari Araçlar deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 65 |                   Hasarlı Araçlar deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 66 |                    Deniz Araçları deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 69 |                  Modifiye Araçlar deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 71 |                               ATV deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 72 |                               UTV deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 74 |           Engelli Plakalı Araçlar deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,1.6 Engine |
| 62 |           Minivan, Van & Panelvan deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,2.0 Engine |
| 67 |                    Klasik Araçlar deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,2.0 Engine |
| 73 |                           Karavan deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     Black,2.0 Engine |
| 70 |                     Hava Araçları deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                        Color |                                                                White |
| 47 | 1 AMG KIRMIZI HATASIZ SERVİS BAKIMLI CLA 200 İLK SAHİBİNDEN |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     White,2.0 Engine |
| 60 |                        Motosiklet deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     White,2.0 Engine |
| 68 |                Elektrikli Araçlar deneme reyonsiverek ilanı |                                                 Color,Engine |                                                     White,2.0 Engine |
```

Comment: It does an overall sort in the filter_option field. I want to sort by color or motor power separately

Black,1.6 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,4.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,5.0 Engine
Black,2.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
White,1.6 Engine
White,2.0 Engine

or

White,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Orange,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Purple,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
White,2.0 Engine
White,2.0 Engine
White,2.0 Engine
Yellow,2.0 Engine

Comment: FYI, putting info like that in a comment is really hard to read. It's better to edit your question and format it a readable way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470136/sorting-filters-in-mysql-group-concat-field

Thank you so much

Comment: That's pretty simple, just reverse the order by, and add an order by in the group_concat.

Answer (score 0):

use alias for group concat column then use order by that column alias name, try this

```
select
ads.id,
ads.ad_title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter.filter_title) filterTitles ,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option ) filterOptions 
from ads
LEFT JOIN ads_filter_option
on find_in_set(ads_filter_option.id,ads.filter_option_id)
LEFT JOIN ads_filter
on ads_filter.id=ads_filter_option.filter_id
where cat_1 = 2
group by ads.id order by filterOptions
```