# Sorting filters in mysql group_concat field

Tags: mysql

I can sort the mysql group_concat field by color. But I can not sort by motor engine power. What can I do for it? color or engine order by ?

[SQL-FIDDLE-TABLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/870f42/1)

```
select
ads.id,
ads.ad_title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter.filter_title SEPARATOR ','),
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',')
from ads
LEFT JOIN ads_filter_option
on find_in_set(ads_filter_option.id,ads.filter_option_id)
LEFT JOIN ads_filter
on ads_filter.id=ads_filter_option.filter_id
where cat_1 = 2
group by ads.id
order by GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',')
```

expected result:

```
White,2.0 Engine
White,2.0 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
Black,2.0 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
Black,1.6 Engine
White,1.6 Engine
White,1.6 Engine
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: change the order to : **order by GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option ORDER BY ads_filter_option.filter_id SEPARATOR ',' )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-query to group_concat by engine power first then use column alias to order by.

```
For example:
select
id,
ad_title,
filter_title,
filter_option_color
from (
   select
   ads.id,
   ads.ad_title,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter.filter_title order by ads_filter.filter_title SEPARATOR ',') filter_title,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option order by ads_filter_option.filter_option SEPARATOR ',') filter_option_power,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads_filter_option.filter_option order by ads_filter_option.filter_option desc SEPARATOR ',') filter_option_color
   from ads
   LEFT JOIN ads_filter_option
   on find_in_set(ads_filter_option.id,ads.filter_option_id)
   LEFT JOIN ads_filter
   on ads_filter.id=ads_filter_option.filter_id
   where cat_1 = 2
       group by ads.id ) t
order by filter_title, filter_option_power desc;

Result:
id  ad_title                                        filter_title    filter_option
60  Motosiklet deneme reyonsiverek ilanı            Color,Engine    White,2.0 Engine
68  Elektrikli Araçlar deneme reyonsiverek ilanı    Color,Engine    White,2.0 Engine
59  Otomobil deneme reyonsiverek ilanı              Color,Engine    Black,2.0 Engine
```

Comment: I edited my answer. You can also order by inside group_concat. This is the critical part of the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been working for a long time :)

Comment: Glad to help. Your sample data helps a lot too.